# Prevent Duplicate Functions in Go for Field-Only Structs

Tags: go, code-duplication

EDIT: I have updated the below code samples to better illustrate the problem.

Let's say I have 2 field-only structs that do not need any functionality.

Assume that they represent 2 types of similar data from a Database:

```
type Boy struct {
    Name          string
    FavoriteColor string
    BirthDay      time.Time
}

type Girl struct {
    Name           string
    FavoriteFlower string
    BirthDay       time.Time
}
```

I write a function for the `Boy` struct that prints a greeting based on the given date and the boy's information.

Assume that this is a placeholder for a much more complicated function that does something based on a `time.Time` field, and returns an `int` that will be used elsewhere in the application:

```
func CheckBirthDayBoy(date time.Time, boy Boy) int {
    numDays := 0

    if date.Before(boy.BirthDay) {
        // Greet how many days before birthday
        numDays = int(boy.BirthDay.Sub(date).Hours() / 24)
        fmt.Println("Hi, " + boy.Name + "! Only " + strconv.Itoa(numDays) + " days until your birthday! I hear your favorite color is " + boy.FavoriteColor + "!")
    } else if date.Equal(boy.BirthDay) {
        // Greet happy birthday
        fmt.Println("Happy birthday, " + boy.Name + "! I brought you something " + boy.FavoriteColor + " as a present!")
    } else {
        // Greet belated birthday
        numDays = int(date.Sub(boy.BirthDay).Hours() / 24)
        fmt.Println("Sorry I'm " + strconv.Itoa(numDays) + " days late, " + boy.Name + "! Here is something " + boy.FavoriteColor + " to cheer you up!")
    }

    return numDays
}
```

Now, since Go is a strongly-typed language, and does not have Generics, I end up having to write a duplicate function just for the `Girl` struct:

```
func CheckBirthDayGirl(date time.Time, girl Girl) int {
    numDays := 0

    if date.Before(girl.BirthDay) {
        // Greet how many days before birthday
        numDays = int(girl.BirthDay.Sub(date).Hours() / 24)
        fmt.Println("Hi, " + girl.Name + "! Only " + strconv.Itoa(numDays) + " days until your birthday! I hear your favorite flower is a " + girl.FavoriteFlower + "!")
    } else if date.Equal(girl.BirthDay) {
        // Greet happy birthday
        fmt.Println("Happy birthday, " + girl.Name + "! I brought you a " + girl.FavoriteFlower + " as a present!")
    } else {
        // Greet belated birthday
        numDays = int(date.Sub(girl.BirthDay).Hours() / 24)
        fmt.Println("Sorry I'm " + strconv.Itoa(numDays) + " days late, " + girl.Name + "! Here is a " + girl.FavoriteFlower + " to cheer you up!")
    }

    return numDays
}
```

Is there a way to avoid code duplication for simple structs like the ones above? I do not want to duplicate my function for each new struct that I want to implement it for.

<s>Interfaces are not an option here because both structs do not have any Functionality to speak of (and adding dummy functionality for the sake of satisfying an Interface sounds like a backwards solution to me).</s>

EDIT: After considering the solution I accepted, I now believe that Interfaces are also a valid solution to this problem. Thanks to @ThunderCat for bringing it up!

Comment: Why dont you just pass `time.Time` to CheckBirthday Function?

Comment: @Hau Ma The above codes have been simplified to illustrate the problem. This can also happen for more complex code.

Comment: How about using a single person and not gendered code. Makes more sense.

Comment: @Derek Hmm... I may need to revise my code samples to better illustrate the problem. Sorry for the confusion. Will update the samples in a few minutes.

Comment: Yeah, I suggest providing an example that is as close to the problem as you can

Comment: Done! Hopefully the updated codes can better illustrate my situation. Thanks!

Comment: Use a function to abstract common code:  `func CheckBirthday(date time.Time, name string, birthday time.Time, thing string) int`.   Call it from `CheckBirthDayGirl` and `CheckBirthDayBoy` with appropriate arguments.

Comment: @ThunderCat Looks like this is the only option in Go, huh?

I just thought of a similar scenario, this time involving struct slices.

Instead of creating 2 or more functions for something that prints the Name for each element in a Boy/Girl slice, I should just create 1 function that accepts a string slice which can be supplied from a Boy/Girl slice. Sounds good?

Comment: Another option is to use interfaces, but that's ruled out in the question for reasons that I don't understand.

Comment: @ThunderCat I ruled out Interfaces because I do not think that the structs needed them, but looking at it again, they are indeed another valid solution. Let me add this note to the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As ThunderCat mentions in the comments: pull common code into a separate function and call.

```
func CheckBirthday(date, birthdate time.Time, name, gift string) (numDays int) {
    if date.Before(birthdate) {
        // Greet how many days before birthday
        numDays = int(birthdate.Sub(date).Hours() / 24)
        fmt.Printf("Hi, %s! Only %d days until your birthday! I hear your favorite is %s!\n", name, numDays, gift)
    } else if date.Equal(birthdate) {
        // Greet happy birthday
        fmt.Printf("Happy birthday, %s! I brought you a %s as a present!\n", name, gift)
    } else {
        // Greet belated birthday
        numDays = int(date.Sub(girl.birthday).Hours() / 24)
        fmt.Printf("Sorry I'm %d days late, %s! Here is a %s to cheer you up!\n", numDays, name, gift)
    }

    return
}

func CheckBirthdayBoy(date time.Time, boy Boy) int {
    return CheckBirthday(date, boy.BirthDay, boy.Name, boy.FavoriteColor)
}

func CheckBirthdayGirl(date time.Time, girl Girl) int {
    return CheckBirthday(date, girl.BirthDay, girl.Name, girl.FavoriteFlower)
}
```

Comment: Note that some of the text doesn't read well anymore, since "Here is a Purple to cheer you up" is nonsense, but the technique is sound.

Comment: Yeah, looks like this is the best option we've got (since type switching and assertion can get pretty crazy when your types increase) until the Go developers add generics to the language (which may never happen since it does tend to add abstraction/complexity). Thanks to you and @ThunderCat for the answer!

Comment: @FloatingSunfish coming from Python and Haskell I agree. Generics are massively powerful, but also remove a lot of type safety you can guarantee in Go (at least without Haskell's overpowered type system!)

Answer (score 2):

Would type switch work for you?

```
func CheckBirthDay(date time.Time, i interface{}) int {
    switch v := i.(type) {
    case Boy:
      CheckBirthDay(date, v.Birthday)
    case Girl:
      CheckBirthDay(date, v.Birthday)
    default:
      DoSomething()
    }
}

func CheckBirthDay(date time.Time, bday time.Time) int {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I thought about this as well, but didn't plan on using it as it can get pretty unmanageable in the long run. Thanks for suggesting, though!